# Running migrations on my Rails DB, adding a column quietly and randomly drops a table without a console error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, migration, schema

I was only able to discouver this problem by slowly walking through running my migrations. For the last two days I've been trying to do somthing simple. Remove one column `verdict:text` from my `simulations` table and add another column: `opinions:hash`.

Doing this caused a variety of errors, such as no method 'my_sym' and saying the simulation table didn't exist.

I initially thought I had resolved this by doing:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:schema:dump
rake db:migrate VERSION="<Migration1>"
rake db:migrate VERSION="<Migration2>"
rake db:setup ENV="test"
```

Migration 1:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => "", limit: 96
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => "", limit: 60

      t.timestamps

      t.index :email, unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

Migration 2:

```
class CreateSimulations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # Needs the hash column worked out before this is run 
    create_table :simulations do |t|
        t.integer :x_size
        t.integer :y_size
        t.string :verdict
        t.string :arrangement 
    end

    add_reference :simulations, :user, index: true    
  end
end
```

This got me back to square one (all my tests worked everything seemed to be in my initial state I had before started having problems), so I re-wrote the two offending migrations thinking they might be the problem, ran the two migrations in this order (I removed the column then added the other one, the opposite order of what I tried previous, thinking maybe the order had some effect).

Migration 3:

```
class RemoveVerdictFromSimulation < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :simulations, :verdict, :string
  end
end
```

Migrations 4:

```
class AddOpinionToSimulations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :simulations, :opinion, :hash
  end
end
```

*Edit: With further investigation it is this 4th migration that is causing the problem of dropping the simulations table without error.*

Both these migrations **worked without error**. However I know doing anything else will cause an error (example running rspec), because it looks like the problem is that one of these migration causes an error with the `schema.rb` file.

After running these last migrations 3&4 my `schema.rb` which previously had both users and simulations tables now looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150807193122) do

# Could not dump table "simulations" because of following NoMethodError
#   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",              limit: 96, default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password", limit: 60, default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

end
```

The particular line of interest here being:

```
# Could not dump table "simulations" because of following NoMethodError
#   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anyone shed some light on whats happening here or how I can fix it? I've been stuck on this for hours.

One thing maybe worth noting, when I re-run the `rake db:schema:dump` I need too comment out my factories for some reason, as they seem to cause errors with simulation table existing. Not sure why they're being called just thought this info might help, here they both are:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
    factory :simulation do |f|
        f.id (Simulation.last.nil? ? 1 : Simulation.last.id + 1)
        f.x_size 3
        f.y_size 3
        f.user_id 1
    end 
end
```

*--*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        email "user_#{User.last.nil? ? 1 : User.last.id + 1}@home.com"
        password "password"
    end
end
```

Comment: What is this "hash" column type about? Are you really trying to store a serialized Hash in the database? SQLite will let you get away with all sorts of strange things but...

Comment: I was told by some one on here hash was a valid data type. It looks like it's the hash migration thats causing the problem. How would I store it instead?

Comment: @muistooshort So I just created the column as a string and serialized it. Im hoping *fingers crossed* this solved my issue. Could you post the hash thing as an answer so I can approve it.

Comment: That's pretty much was suggesting while you added your comment. You might have some manual cleaning up to do though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is right here:

```
class AddOpinionToSimulations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :simulations, :opinion, :hash
  end
end
```

There's no such thing as `hash` column type. SQLite will, unfortunately, let you create columns with any type you want (with unrecognized things being treated as strings) but ActiveRecord won't know what to do with them. The result is that your migration works but the schema dump fails because ActiveRecord can't say:

```
t.hash :opinion
```

in the `schema.rb` file.

If you really think you want to store a Hash in a column, you'd create a `text` column:

```
add_column :simulations, :opinion, :text
```

and then use [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) in your model:

```
serialize :opinion, Hash
```

Of course that leaves you with an opaque blob of YAML in your database that you won't be able to (sanely) query so it should only be used if you are okay with that.

A better solution would be to normalize your `opinion` Hashes so that you could store their information in separate tables/models.

Comment: The creating specific columns for opinions is actually a good idea.. it's only three keys and only two of them get used, so not a bad idea. Thanks again for saving me from this headache.

Comment: I tend to pretend that `serialize` doesn't exist, it is a quick hack that leads to nasty problems. Separate columns or tables is a much better approach.

Comment: Unrelated but I can't PM you- in the spirit of avoiding serializing, how would you _recommend_ storing a 2d array of strings?

Comment: Really depends on how you want to work with it inside the database. Would switching to PostgreSQL be an option? That supports array columns.

Comment: Sort of outside of scope of this project. Im serializing as an array right now.. I wont really need to query its a smaller project, Im just wondering if theres a better design choice.

Comment: If you don't need to query it and you know that you'll never need to then `serialize` is fine.